# I want to check which Vin has abs value in column Module

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

[image]

I want to check which Vin has abs value in column Module. If it has then in the Result column I want Yes wherever that number is present in the column Vin.

Comment: `df.loc[df['Module'] == 'abs', 'Vin']`

Comment: The expected output should be Yes or NO  in the Result column(Column C). I want result like I have mentioned in column C

Comment: Then `df['C'] = (df['Module'] == 'abs').map({True: 'Yes', False: 'No'})`

Comment: Hi, @richardec thanks for the reply. You are partially correct. As I mentioned I want Yes if 'abs' is available in particular VIN number. but if that vin no. is repeated in a column then it should right Yes because 'abs' is available for that vin no.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't notice that. I reopened and answered your question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first check all the rows where `Module == "abs"`, and then group the result by `Vin`, and use `transform('any')` to convert each group to rows of `True` if the group contains a single `True`, rows of `False` otherwise:

```
df['Result'] = df['Module'].eq('abs').groupby(df['Vin']).transform('any').map({True: 'Yes', False: 'No'})
```